# flask error with sqlalchemy when doing rollback

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, sqlalchemy

My error handler for 500 is throwing an error at `db.session.rollback`.

```
@bp.app_errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):
    db.session.rollback()
    return render_template('errors/500.html'), 500
```

I tried to catch the error with try..except as follows:

```
try:
    db.session.rollback()
except sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError:
    pass
finally:
    return render_template('errors/500.html'), 500
```

The error still persists with the result of not rendering the `500.html` template. Error is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'committed' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction.
```

Is there a way to check if `db.session` is in a state where rollback is possible?

**EDIT:**

While it's a valid question, further debugging revealed that the error originates from an earlier `commit` in the code, rather than the `rollback`.

Answer (score 1):

check if `db.session.is_active` then `rollback()`